# Need to consolidate many rows into one based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Been working at this all day and can't seem to make any progress.
I have data like this:

```
MemberID    Group           MemberStatusType    ContactTask         Jan Assess Date     Jan RF Score    Jan PF Score    Feb Assess Date     Feb RF Score    Feb PF Score    Mar Assess Date     Mar RF Score    Mar PF Score
5213        MSO             Engaged X           Follow Up Contact   1/31/2012           1               4               NULL                        NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL
5213        MSO             Engaged X           Follow Up Contact   NULL                NULL            NULL            2/29/2012                   2                   2           NULL            NULL            NULL
5213        MSO             Engaged X           Follow Up Contact   NULL                NULL            NULL            NULL                        NULL            NULL        3/21/2012           5               4
```

What I am trying to end up with is data like this:

```
MemberID    Group   MemberStatusType    ContactTask         Jan Assess Date     Jan RF Score        Jan PF Score        Feb Assess Date     Feb RF Score    Feb PF Score    Mar Assess Date     Mar RF Score        Mar PF Score
5213        MSO         Engaged X       Follow Up Contact   1/31/2012               1                   4               2/29/2012               2               2           3/21/2012               5                   4
```

I have experimented with PIVOT but I didn't like the results because I don't need to aggregate anything.  I just need to take the data from multiple rows and make it all go on to one row.  I have also seen a few examples of doing things like this on this site but I wasn't able to get those things to work either or some were for oracle or mysql and I didn't know how to translate to MS SQL.

Comment: You say you don't need to aggregate anything, but that's what that is right there.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an aggregation:

```
select MemberId, Group, MemberStatusType, ContactTask,
       max([Jan Assess Date]) as [Jan Assess Date],
       . . .
from t
group by MemberId, Group, MemberStatusType, ContactTask;
```

The `max()` function will serve to return the non-null value (if any) among the rows.

Comment: This did not work.  What this did was make the output look like what I have in the table I began with only Jan is on the bottom row, with March on the top row.  Just flipped the results.